# Android Broadcasts - sending and receiving with permissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I try to implement the permission approach of `BroadcastReceiver`.

In **sender** class, I try to send a normal broadcast

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.vn.BroadcastReceiver");
    intent.putExtra("Foo", "Bar");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

with `AndroidManifest` file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.nhp"/>
```

In **receiver** class, I write a custom `FirstBroadcastReceiver`

```
    public class FirstBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final String TAG = FirstBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + intent.getStringExtra("Foo"));
        }
    }
```

and its `AndroidManifest`

```
    <permission android:name="com.nhp" />

    <receiver
        android:permission="com.nhp"
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".receivers.FirstBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.vn.BroadcastReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I install **receiver** application first and **sender** then. And it worked!!

But when I try to call `sendBroadcast(intent,"com.nhp");`, it never trigger any thing. Anyone can explain for me why? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom permission should be declared in the sender and the receiver should request for it.

Moreover, broadcast receiver doesn't need the `android:permission` attribute. You should only use it if sender must have a specific permission.

---

**Sender**

The sender declares the custom permission in its manifest

```
<permission android:name="com.nhp" />
```

and sends the broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.vn.BroadcastReceiver");
intent.putExtra("Foo", "Bar");
sendBroadcast(intent, "com.nhp");
```

**Receiver**

The receiver requests for the custom permission in its manifest and listens for broadcasts

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.nhp"/>
...
...
...
<receiver
    android:exported="true"
    android:name=".receivers.FirstBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.vn.BroadcastReceiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Of course, [the order of the installations is important](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#restricting_broadcasts_with_permissions) and the sender app must be installed first as it defines the custom permission.

> Note: Custom permissions are registered when the app is installed. The app that defines the custom permission must be installed before the app that uses it.

Comment: Great! Thank you